# Users of PowerApp can't get secret from azure key vault (through Power Automate)

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, powerapps, power-automate

For a azure keyvault connection in Power Automate I am using an app registration. Users of a PowerApp I made can't seem to get secrets from the azure key vault unless I give them access to the keyvault. I was hoping adding the users to the acces policies in the keyvault would be enough.
Is there a way to let users get secrets in a PowerApp (through Power Automate) without giving them full access to the keyvault?

I am trying to do something similar as [this](https://sharepains.com/2020/09/23/azure-key-vault-and-power-automate/)

Answer (score 0):

You could grant them the "get" permission only on secrets:

```sh
az keyvault set-policy --name myvault --secret-permissions get --upn <user ID/email>
```

However, a better approach might be to run your application as a service principal (or have middleware service that does - really depends on *why* users need access to the secrets) and it contact Key Vault directly. That service principal should be given minimal rights - basically the same command as above, except using `--spn` instead of `--upn`.